# Unable to Use wifi in Hp Pavilion 15 ab522TX

Tags: wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I am having Hp Pavilion 15 ab522TX. I have recently Installed Ubuntu 16.0.4 along with Windows 10 (Duel Boot). I am not able to access wifi in the system. It shows no wifi driver. See the [wireless diagnostics log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23541727/).

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:4a:3e:f5:02:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:94100000-94107fff
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  signon-keyring-extension
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,515 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 248596 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) over (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-47-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-47-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.19~16.04.1+0.8-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.5) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
```

Still there is no sign of Wifi.

Then I tried, `dkms status` and I got the output:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I had tried varies method posted in the community. Nothing worked.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. i have tried most of the posts given by the community. If you have any specific way to solve it kindly send me a link.

Comment: I have executed the things that you had commented. I reinstalled Ubuntu 6 times.   Wifi works well in my Windows 10. This is the result after executing the command 
 wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23541727/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but it doesn't look like a description of steps that I or anybody could follow to retrace them. Which steps did you take and which commands did you run to (try to) install the wireless adapter drivers on Ubuntu?

Comment: Sincerely i don't remember what are the commands that i had used. You may tell me what i have to use and if it works  i shall inform. Meanwhile i shall tell some of  the commands that i had used                                                                                                                                     sudo apt-get install  bcmwl kernel- source

Comment: Output is like                                                                                                           Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 172 not upgraded.

Comment: i tried to execute    bcmwl-kernel-source . the output is https://paste.ubuntu.com/23549124/ . No effect in WiFi

Comment: <pre><code>dkms status    <br/>
    bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed</code></pre>

Comment: output of the command    sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source is    https://paste.ubuntu.com/23552179/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get “Required key not available” when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](/q/762254/175814)

Comment: That was the crucial piece of information and this is why I asked you to describe in detail what you did and what happened in the first place. We could have resolved that 2 days ago. ;-]

Comment: "Why do I get “Required key not available” when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?  " This link helped me. I had tried this one before also  and it did not work. But now after disabling the secure boot i am getting the WiFi. Thanks so much. I see that people have badges and reputations in this site. In What way can i thank you for your help? Once again thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I flagged your question for moderator attention so it can be closed as a different, more appropriate duplicate. Since it's a duplicate you can't help me in the context of this question. However once you earned 15 reputation you can (and should) [vote](/help/privileges/vote-up) for answers on the linked question (and the question itself) if you found them helpful (or well stated in the case of the question). If you really want to you can also go through some of my past [answers](/users/175814/?tab=answers&sort=votes) and [questions](/users/175814/?tab=questions&sort=votes) and vote for them.